# javascript promise <value> undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

So i'm trying to passa a jQuery ajax request via promise like this:

```
var foo;
foo = bar().then(function(response) {
    console.log("Success!", response);
    console.log(foo[0].bool);
}, function(error) {
    console.error("Failed!", error);
});

console.log(foo);

function bar(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, rejected){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'foo.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                resolve(data);
            }
        }).fail(function(xhr){
            rejected(xhr);
        })
    })
    }
```

Everthing works well inside the `then()`, console.log show exactly what I want, but when I use `console.log(foo)` it shows `Promise { <state>: "fulfilled", <value>: undefined }`

I'm not understanding whats is happening here, can anyone clarify?

Comment: what is the expected result? i would expect `Promise { <state>: "pending"}`

Comment: Just wonder, why are you manually creating a promise? `$.ajax` returns a promise. If you want to stick to native implementation simply use `Promise.resolve().then(function(){return $.ajax()})`

Comment: @RolandStarke something like an array of objects send by my `foo.php` like `[0]: {bool: 'foo', id: 'bar'}`

Comment: @RolandStarke why do you expect to `Promise {<state>: "pending"}`?

Comment: as you can read at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then the then method returns another Promise.

Comment: Instead of `console.log(foo)` you need to do `foo.then(console.log.bind(console))`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unfortunately one of the many things when dealing with async javascript that trips up many in the early days.

As an alternative to what you are trying to do, you would assign `foo` in the same way you are doing it, and then pass that Promise around instead. Then when you need the result of the ajax request, use `.then()`:

```
foo.then(ajaxResult => console.log(ajaxResult));
```